# facebookcorewwwi problems on Tor

Tags: onion-services, help, error

I am trying to access
https://facebookcorewwwi.onion/  but it fails after login on https://facebookcorewwwi.onion/checkpoint/?next
with the error message

> Sorry, something went wrong
>
> Please try closing and re-opening your browser window.

Retrying the browser doesn't help.

Any ideas? How can I troubleshoot it further?
Guess the problem is coz I've checkpoint enabled for my account?

Comment: Have you enable java script for that domain? 
If not - then try again after enabling it.
(Click the button on top left with the 'S' on it and temporarily allow for that domain).
Lot's of things on facebook needs java.

Comment: Thank @StigAtleSteffensen but enabling JS did not help either. I whitelisted facebook as well as disabled globally for testing, still no luck. facebook.com works fine though.

Comment: Try mobile version of Facebook. https://m.facebookcorewwwi.onion/ Otherwise the issue will be enabled **Checkpoint**.